# Transpose Excel column to rows

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

I have an Excel sheet that looks like the first picture and I want to convert it to the second picture:
[image]

I have written the following code but it does not work as expected. It deletes more rows than expected. What's wrong with the code?

```
Sub Trans3()
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Integer, Z As Integer, Q As Integer, T As Integer

Set rng = Range("B1")
While rng.Value <> ""

 For Each y In Range("A1:A10")
    I = I + 1
    J = I
    Z = 1
    Do While Cells(J + 1, 1).Value = Cells(J, 1).Value
        J = J + 1
    Loop                     
    Set rng2 = Range("B" & I & ":B" & J)

    If I > 1 Then
       Z = J - I + 1
    Else
        Z = J
    End If

    rng2.Resize(Z).Copy
    Range("C" & I).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    T = I

    Do While J > 1
       Q = T + 1
       Rows(Q).EntireRow.Delete
       J = J - 1
   Loop

 Next y
Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did a little refactoring.  I moved everything into arrays to speed it up.

See notes in code for reference.

```
Sub FOOO()
Dim inArr() As Variant
Dim outArr() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cntrw As Long
Dim cntclm As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws
    Set rng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    'find the max number column that will be needed in the output
    cntclm = ws.Evaluate("MAX(COUNTIF(" & rng.Address & "," & rng.Address & "))") + 1
    'find the number of rows that will be needed in the output.
    cntrw = ws.Evaluate("SUM(1/COUNTIF(" & rng.Address & "," & rng.Address & "))")
    'put the existing data into an an array
    inArr = rng.Resize(, 2).Value
    'resize output array to the extents needed
    ReDim outArr(1 To cntrw, 1 To cntclm)
    'put the first value in the first spot in the output
    outArr(1, 1) = inArr(1, 1)
    outArr(1, 2) = inArr(1, 2)
    'these are counters to keep track of which slot the data should go.
    j = 3
    k = 1
    'loop through the existing data rows
    For i = 2 To UBound(inArr, 1)
        'test whether the data in A has changed or not.
        If inArr(i, 1) = inArr(i - 1, 1) Then
            'if not put the value in B in the next slot and iterate to the next column
            outArr(k, j) = inArr(i, 2)
            j = j + 1
        Else
            'if change start a new line in the outarr and fill the first two slots
            k = k + 1
            j = 3
            outArr(k, 1) = inArr(i, 1)
            outArr(k, 2) = inArr(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    'remove old data
    .Range("A:B").Clear
    'place new data in its place.
    .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(outArr, 1), UBound(outArr, 2)).Value = outArr
End With
End Sub
```

This does require that the data be sorted on column A.

Comment: +voted for speed due to formula usage, for all unique values in the data set.

Answer (score 1):

My take on this problem .

```
Sub test()

    Dim lCtrRow_Raw     As Long
    Dim lCtrRow_New     As Long
    Dim lInst           As Long

    Dim dctUniq         As New Dictionary
    Dim sKey
    Dim arrRaw
    Dim arrNew()

    '/ Specify your range here. Only two columns of data should be used.
    arrRaw = Selection() ' ****Avoid using Selection in actual code****.

    '/ Filter Duplicates.
    For lCtrRow_Raw = LBound(arrRaw) To UBound(arrRaw)
        If Not dctUniq.Exists(arrRaw(lCtrRow_Raw, 1)) Then
            dctUniq.Add arrRaw(lCtrRow_Raw, 1), arrRaw(lCtrRow_Raw, 1)
        End If
    Next

    '/ Start New Array
    ReDim arrNew(1 To dctUniq.Count, 1 To 1)

    '/ Seed IDs
    For Each sKey In dctUniq.Keys
        lCtrRow_New = lCtrRow_New + 1
        arrNew(lCtrRow_New, 1) = dctUniq(sKey)
    Next

    '/ Loop and assign unique values
    For lCtrRow_New = LBound(arrNew) To UBound(arrNew)
      lInst = 1
     For lCtrRow_Raw = LBound(arrRaw) To UBound(arrRaw)
            If arrRaw(lCtrRow_Raw, 1) = arrNew(lCtrRow_New, 1) Then
                lInst = lInst + 1
                If lInst > UBound(arrNew, 2) Then
                    ReDim Preserve arrNew(1 To dctUniq.Count, 1 To lInst)
                End If

                arrNew(lCtrRow_New, lInst) = arrRaw(lCtrRow_Raw, 2)
            End If
       Next
    Next

    '/ Dump array in the data sheet.
    'Sheet1.Range("A20").Resize(UBound(arrNew, 1), UBound(arrNew, 2)).Value = arrNew
End Sub
```

Comment: I would be interested in speed, yours compared to mine on large data sets.  you do a lot of looping but I have the two formulas.  It would be interesting, but not enough for me to test. :)

Comment: You win, on 10,000 rows into 26 categories, yours was nearly instantaneous, while mine took 4 seconds.

Comment: I did some testing too. Same with 26 letters and 10000 rows. I did win. But if you change the data to have 10000 unique values, your's code is faster by a mile. So there you win. :)

Comment: So you are saying that I should have stacked the deck better? :)  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Shank, using your code, I've made minor modifications and now it deletes the right number of rows and it works, try it out.

```
Sub Transpose()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet_Name") ' modify here to your Worksheet name
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    For row = 1 To LastRow
        If sht.Cells(row, 1) <> "" Then
            i = i + 1
            j = i
            Z = 1
            Do While Cells(j + 1, 1).Value = Cells(j, 1).Value
                j = j + 1
            Loop

            Set rng2 = Range("B" & i & ":B" & j)

            If i > 1 Then
                Z = j - i + 1
            Else
                Z = j
            End If

            rng2.Resize(Z).Copy
            Range("C" & i).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
            T = i

            Do While j - row > 0
                Q = T + 1
                Rows(Q).EntireRow.Delete
                j = j - 1
            Loop
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thnx tgis works...so basically i delete few extra rows that you solved by j-row. and this is helpful LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    For row = 1 To LastRow.... I didnt know about this

Comment: @Shank you are welcome, please mark as answer and upvote

Comment: FWIW, though this works, for large data sets this will be much slower than the array version.

Comment: @ScottCraner I agree, I can write my own code version that will work faster using arrays (like you mentioned), but I tried using Shank's code and request to solve his problem. Besides, as I saw from more experienced users here, isn't this site for assisting with errors people get with their code attempts, and not writing code for other people.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, you answered the question.  Sometimes though it is better to give them what they need over what they want.  I have found that many questioners do not know what is possible.  Also we need to remember the future viewers of these questions.  So if they show effort and a better method exists I will give them the better method.  My FWIW was simply a statement of fact that Arrays are faster then the continual reference to the worksheet and not a judgement of your answer.  Also since this question is asked so many times I wanted one that I can use for reference in the future.