# Convert multiple rows to columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet containing clients and their dependents. It is listed as

SSN                   Last Name      First Name      Relationship 
000-00-0000      Smith              John                Client
000-00-0000      Smith              Freddy            Son
000-00-0000      Smith              Beth                Daughter
111-11-1111       Johnson          Alan                Client
111-11-1111       Johnson          Carla              Spouse

I need it listed with just the clients as the row, and dependents listed beside (next columns), like this:

SSN                   Last Name      First Name      Dep1 FN     Dep1 Rel     Dep2 FN     Dep2 Rel
000-00-0000      Smith              John                Freddy         Son              Beth            Daughter
111-11-1111       Johnson          Alan                 Carla           Spouse

SSN is the determining factor on this, since sometimes the last names will be different. I have seen some VBA questions that have had similar answers, but I can't seem to find something to modify for this specifically.

EDIT:

The code that I have already tried is:

```
Sub tgr()

Dim wsInput As Worksheet
Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim ACell As Range
Dim arrResults() As Variant
Dim ResultIndex As Long
Dim sCurrent As String
Dim sLine As String

Set wsInput = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
Set wsOutput = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

With wsInput.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .Sort .Resize(, 1), xlAscending, .Offset(, 1).Resize(, 1), , xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
    ReDim arrResults(1 To .Cells.Count, 1 To 1)
    For Each ACell In .Resize(, 1).Cells
        If ACell.Value & "|" & ACell.Offset(, 1).Value <> sCurrent Then
            sCurrent = ACell.Value & "|" & ACell.Offset(, 1).Value
            ResultIndex = ResultIndex + 1
            arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) = sCurrent
        End If
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) = arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) & "|" & ACell.Offset(, 2).Value
    Next ACell
End With

With wsOutput.Range("A1").Resize(ResultIndex)
    .Parent.UsedRange.Clear
    .Value = arrResults
    .TextToColumns .Cells, xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
End With
End Sub
```

I found this on a different question, but it is listing out things how I need them, except just the last names of dependents beside the client. No relationship or first name or anything. I know NOTHING about VBA, so I'm not sure what parts of this code to change.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT 2:

Report as it comes from our database:

[image]

How I need the report to look:

[image]

Comment: Now that you have told us what you want, please share the code you have tried and what it is doing that is in error.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.

Comment: The way your have your data now is the preferred data layout because of how formulas such as CountIf work, as well as being able to filter.  The format you want is much harder to work with and I would recommend against it.

Comment: Edited to include the code I tried.

Also, a column based report will not work for what I am wanting to do with the data, which is why I need it row based. I am mail merging 5000 clients, and need their dependent information merged as well.

Comment: here are some examples that do something similar.  It would need to be modified a little, but the logic is similar.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272074/transpose-excel-column-to-rows

Comment: @ScottCraner, thank you. That helps. I edited post again to include images of how my report comes out from our database. I'm unsure how to change the code in what you linked in order to include multiple cells of data when I am converting, if that makes sense. I can't just move one field, which is how that code works. Like I said, I've no experience at all with VBA, so if you could just let me know which lines I need to look more into, I will start some research!

Comment: @ScottCraner any advice? I'm very confused as to how to adjust the number of columns I am transferring.

Comment: Sorry as I am a volunteer, I do not have the time to rework this for you. suffice it to say with my answer in the link above you will want to multiply `cntclm` by 3 when setting up the output array.  Then loop through the columns in the first report and put each of the three criteria you want from each row.