# find duplicate in 2 columns and paste adjacent rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried, and been unable to find any sample VBA code that fits my needs. What I'm trying to do is find duplicate matches between two columns and consolidate them with respect to a third column, then in a fourth column show how many instances of the duplicate existed originally.

**The original data:**

[image]

**The ideal output after removing duplicates:**

[image: screen shot]

As you can see, in the output I have 1 instance of `1` in `Column A`, `a` in `Column B`, retained the first value the duplicates started at in `Column C` and express `2` occurences of the duplicates in `Column D`. Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: here is one that does it for one column, try modifying it for two columns.  When you get stuck please come back and ask a specific question as to what the problem you have.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me service: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272074/transpose-excel-column-to-rows

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner the link helped me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below code will find the number of occurrences in fourth column and remove the duplicates

```
Sub foo()

row_count = 20

For i = 2 To row_count
    Count = 1
    For j = 2 To row_count
        If i <> j And Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(j, 1).Value And Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(j, 2).Value Then
                Rows(j & ":" & j).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                Count = Count + 1
                j = j - 1
            End If
        End If
    Next j
    If Count > 1 Then
        Cells(i, 4).Value = Count
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```