# How could i arrange the following in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with the given date in Column A and B. I want to convert the same as shown on right side of the picture

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because '*How could i arrange the following in excel*' is **not** a specific programming problem; it isn't even an adequate title to a question. Please abide by the [rules and guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) that **you agreed to** when you joined this community.

Comment: here is a vba approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272074/transpose-excel-column-to-rows

Comment: sir, i make the required changes

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and where you have run into a problem.  This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with code or complicated formulas you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How does this question differ from your previous [How to Arrange the repetitive values in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260240/how-to-arrange-the-repetitive-values-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use formula approach, then please add this formula `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$14,SMALL(IF($D2=$A$2:$A$14,ROW($A$2:$A$14)-ROW($A$2)+1),COLUMN(A2))),"")` in cell `E2`. When entering formula please use `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` combination, since this is array formula. After you confirmed formula, drag it across your area `E2:H5`.

[image]